# Selected TextBox deselecting when I change ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I am making myself a project manager and I need to refresh Project List every so often. When I am refreshing the Project Manager, I want to select the item that was previously selected. But that selection causes my text box to unselect, therefore, what happens is that that text box unselects after typing one key.

So outline what happens:

- I try to edit one text box
- Edition causes update in project -> program calls RefreshProjectList()
- RefreshProjectList() on marked position causes selected text box to unselect
- Result: You must select text box after writing one symbol

[*Picture if useful*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKok9.jpg)

[*These selected text boxes are struggling to be edited*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNEiX.png)

Code:

```
    private void RefreshProjectList() {
        if (BlockListReload)
            return;

        Project selected = (Project)ProjectList.SelectedItem;
        ProjectList.Items.Clear();
        CurrentlyShown.Clear();

        foreach(Project p in Projects){
            if (p.state == State.Planned && ShowPlanned.Checked) {
                CurrentlyShown.Add(p);
                ProjectList.Items.Add(p);
            }
            if (p.state == State.Active && ShowActive.Checked) {
                CurrentlyShown.Add(p);
                ProjectList.Items.Add(p);
            }
            if (p.state == State.Finished && ShowFinished.Checked) {
                CurrentlyShown.Add(p);
                ProjectList.Items.Add(p);
            }
            if (p.state == State.Delayed && ShowDelayed.Checked) {
                CurrentlyShown.Add(p);
                ProjectList.Items.Add(p);
            }
        }

        if (selected == null)
            return;

        if (ProjectList.Items.Contains(selected)) {
            ProjectList.SelectedItem = selected; // IF I REMOVE THIS
        } else {
            if (ProjectList.Items.Count > 0)
                ProjectList.SelectedIndex = 0; // OR THIS LINE, EVERYTHING WORKS
        }
    }
```

If you need more code, I will be happy to provide, but I don't want to spam you with loads of unuseful code.

Q: Why does changing selected item in ListBox cause deselecting of TextBox and how to prevent it?

Comment: I don't think error is in code shown.  I think you somehow are creating a new instance of the form which is re-initializing the entire form.

Comment: @jdweng I am sure that problem is caused by those lines marked (//HERE), because if I comment those lines out, everything works well. (Except that ListBox isn't keeping its selection, which is why I am doing it)

Comment: Is HideSelection on?

Comment: what is `CurrentlyShown`? Your code seems to work only on `ProjectList` (the ListView on the right, I assume) and call Clear and Add on CurrentlyShown: I would check these methods: maybe you are moving selection there

Comment: @TaW It is set on true.

Comment: @Gian Paolo CurrentlyShown is a List of projects that are currently shown in the left menu of the program. The bug doesn't happen if I remove those lines marked (//HERE), so I am sure that there's the problem. Thanks for the tip, though, I'll try to look into them.

Answer (score 0):

Several controls that have selectable text or items also come with a property `HideSelection`.

This includes:

- `TextBox`
- `RichTextBox`
- `ListView`

but not

- `ListBox`
- `CheckedListBox`
- `DataGridView`

Like it or not it always defaults to `true` so the selection is hidden whenever the focus is off the control..

Simply set it to `false` in the designer and you can see all selection no matter where the focus is..

Comment: The problem is not that I don't see a selection, the problem is that if I try to write something in any of those text boxes, those two lines I marked in the code cause the deselection of the text box. So if I wanted to write something longer in them, I would have to click on them every time after writing a symbol.

Comment: Well, I don't know what you mean by 'writing something longer' or 'writing a symbol'; but as long as HideSelection is true you can't see a selection until you move the focus to the textbox; if you do that by clicking the selection of course is really gone. First set HideSelection= false, then maybe add a testbutton which reports the SelectedText of one of the boxes. If it really is empty then go really do have a __second__ problem. Do start by fixing the __first__ one though..!

Comment: My bad, I can never explain things, hope I will now.
Normally you can write in textboxes any number of characters without a problem. But I my case you write a character in textbox and thanks to those two lines marked the textbox deselects, so you can no longer write in it. Therefore I end in a situation where I would have to select that textbox every time I type a character.

Answer (score 0):

OMG. I honestly don't know why I did not see it.

```
ProjectList.SelectedItem = selected;
//where ProjectList is ListBox<Project> and selected is Project
```

I am selecting an item in the ProjectList(ListBox). I didn't realize that it was calling a `ProjectList_SelectedIndexChanged()` event which was doing it.

EDIT: SOLVED by adding this:

```
        if (focused != null) {
            this.ActiveControl = focused;
            focused.Select(focused.TextLength,0);
        }
```

Where focused is a TextBox I set to last selected TextBox and this is the form.
Thanks TaW.

Comment: __If__ all is solved you should decide if you have an answered question, which is useful to others or if the problem was just a typo etc.. In the latter case it should be closed and eventually deleted from SO. If your problems are not all solved this is not an answer and you should edit the question.. Anyway: Selecting an item in a ListBox will __not__ delesect anything. Unless you have code to that effect, maybe in the selectedindexchanged or the selectedvaluechanged event..

Comment: @TaW Added solution, I still don't know why it was happening, but I manually selected the TextBox which was previously selected.

Comment: Good for you if you are happy. Please do however take care to make the disctinction between __Focus__ and __Selection__. The TextBox lost __focus__ when you clicked (or tabbed) somewhere else but it neither lost its __TextSelection__ (which just was __hidden__) not did itself 'lose selection' because a control in a running program __can't__ be __selected__ anyway, just __focused__!

Comment: @TaW It **was** actually in the event, I totally didn't realize that.